# Network and Call not working in particular region, mobile settings issue

Tags: xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I am using Redmi Note 4 and Jio sim.

My internet and calls are not working inspite of network available. Other people living near me is able to use internet well at that place.
When I move about 70 meter away from my home, internet and calls are working quite fine. Internet and calls are working everywhere, except at my home. Means problem is under particular tower.

At my home, I changed my sim card and inserted in my friend's Redmi note 4 mobile, my internet and calls started working fine. But her jio sim inserted in my Redmi note 4, then it is not working. It means, problem is not in SIM card  but in my mobile setting.

Tried Solutions:

I thought I messed up in *#*#4636#*#* settings, but I have no options to make it default setting. So, In mobile setting, I made default network setting.

Final solution:

I formatted my mobile completely, three times, so that all settings get as it was in new mobile. But still the problem is unsolved.

Please let me know, what should I do ?

Comment: Please try to add APN settings of jio of the mentioned second phone into your phone and check.